# How to control starting bin range for Choropleth map using GeoPandas

Tags: python, legend, geopandas, choropleth, bins

I created a Choropleth map using GeoPandas with 4 discrete bins rather than using a continuous colormap. It worked fine but the ranges of values in the legend was 2.40-3.11, 3.11-3.81, etc. I would like to have 2.00-3.00, 3.00-4.00, etc. I'm using this code:

```
    ax = merged.dropna().plot(column='% increase', cmap='Blues', 
    figsize=(40, 10), scheme='User_Defined',classification_kwds=dict(bins=[3,4,5,6]), k=4, 
    legend=True, linewidth=0.75, edgecolor='grey')
```

This almost works! The first range however starts with the minimum value (2.40) but otherwise is what I need, i.e. 2.40-3.00, 3.00-4.00, etc. Anyone any suggestions of how to force the first range in the legend to start with 2.00 rather than the minimum value?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the label in the legend (which I assume is the case as choropleth bins are correct), you can do it manually by getting labels from axis and changing them.

```
ax = merged.dropna().plot(column='% increase', cmap='Blues', 
    figsize=(40, 10), scheme='User_Defined',classification_kwds=dict(bins=[3,4,5,6]), k=4, 
    legend=True, linewidth=0.75, edgecolor='grey')

leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.get_texts()[0].set_text('2.00-3.00')
```

Comment: That works perfectly and the fact that I can add any text I like is a bonus.